# How to save auth status after submitting post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have this blog-like app and there is a problem that every time i sumbit a post my authorisation status is refreshing and im unlogged again.
Idk if i should save the status with localstorage and how to properly do that or there is better way, maybe cookies. I will be very thankful for any help

CreatePost.js

```
import { addDoc, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebaseconf';

class CreatePost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            setTitle: "",
            setPostText: "",
        };
    }

    sTitle = (event) => {
        this.setState({ setTitle: (event.target.value) });
    }

    sPostText = (event) => {
        this.setState({ setPostText: (event.target.value) });
    }

    collectionRef = collection(db, "posts");


    createPost = async () => {
        await addDoc(this.collectionRef, { title: this.state.setTitle || null, postText: this.state.setPostText || null });
        window.location.pathname = "/";
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="cpPage">
                <div className="cpContainer">
                    <h1>Create a Post</h1>
                    <div className="inputGp">
                        <label>Title:</label>
                        <input
                            placeholder="Title..."
                            onChange={this.sTitle}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="inputGp">
                        <label>Post:</label>
                        <textarea
                            placeholder="Write your post..."
                            onChange={this.sPostText}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={this.createPost}>Add your post</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default CreatePost;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/main.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import CreatePost from './pages/CreatePost';
import Login from './pages/Login';

import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./firebaseconf";


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuth: false,
      setIsAuth: false
    };
  }

  signIn = () => {
    this.setState({ setIsAuth: true });
  }
  signUserOut = () => {
    signOut(auth).then(() => {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.setState({ setIsAuth: false });
      window.location.pathname = "/login";
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          {!this.state.setIsAuth ? (
            <Link to="/login"> Login </Link>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Link to="/createpost"> Create Post </Link>
              <button onClick={this.signUserOut}> Log Out</button>
            </>)}
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login setIsAuth={this.signIn} />} />
          <Route path="/createpost" element={<CreatePost setIsAuth={this.signIn} />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: the page is refreshing because you're manually  changing the url by     `window.location.pathname = / `  why are you doing that

Comment: i just want to redirect user to home page, but not to log out

Answer (score 0):

Firstly keeping track of if there is a authenticated user as you do is unnecessary - instead check if Firebases built in `auth().currentUser` is/isn’t null. Firebase for react automatically handles all auth cookies for you automatically.

Secondly use `router` to redirect/change pages - changing the window location can/will reload the app and the current user will briefly be null as Firebase will be briefly asynchronous be checking the cookies/re-authorizing the user.

Thirdly Firebase for react has a built in `auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {})` stream you can listen to to make any updates when the auth state changes.